# Cant select elment from xml with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a specific Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Address">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Recipient" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and a simple xslt file. If I try to select the value of the attribute "name" from the tags which named "element" the output is nothing.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0'
    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' >
    <xsl:template match="element">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element` in your XML is in the namespace bound to prefix `xs`, so `match="element"` didn't find a match. You need to define `xs` prefix (or any prefix name, as long as it is mapped to the correct namespace URI) in your XSLT and use `match="xs:element"` :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0'
    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
    <xsl:template match="xs:element">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**<kbd>[`xsltransform.net demo`](http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQfF/1)</kbd>**